# Need current help on css3 animation-play-state

Tags: css

I just need to know if an animation changes the original css values that were defined  before the animation takes place?

As far as I know the answer is *yes* but I have a problem. I placed an image within a div and I want to run an animation on it only when it gets hovered. Animation-play-state set to "paused" in image helped me stop animation till  the hovering has occured on image. On hovering the image ,the animation-play-state is set to "running".

Everything was going fine but suddenly I noticed that if the animation changes the original css value then a previously set animation-play-state to "paused" should also be changed permanently when hover on image occurs and keep on playing animation after that. But the animation is playing only on hover state! Why?

HTML

```
<div class="hs-wrapper">
    <img src="i.jpg" alt="image01"/>
    <img src="a.jpg" alt="image01"/>
    <img src="c.jpg" alt="image03"/>
    <img src="d.jpg" alt="image04"/>
    <img src="e.jpg" alt="image05"/>
    <img src="f.jpg" alt="image06"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hs-wrapper img {
    width: 333px;
    height: 500px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation: showMe 0.8s linear infinite 0s forwards;
    -moz-animation: showMe 0.8s linear infinite 0s forwards;
    -o-animation: showMe 0.8s linear infinite 0s forwards;
    -ms-animation: showMe 0.8s linear infinite 0s forwards;
    animation: showMe 0.8s linear infinite 0s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused;
    -ms-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

.hs-wrapper:hover img {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    -moz-animation-play-state: running;
    -o-animation-play-state: running;
    -ms-animation-play-state: running;
    animation-play-state: running;
}

@-moz-keyframes showMe {
    0% {
        visibility: visible;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    12.5% {
        visibility: visible;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    25% {
        visibility: hidden;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    100% {
        visibility: hidden;
        z-index: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more precise and try to write down good English. Also make your code better readable. I edited both your text and your code.

Comment: @Bram Vanroy Everything is fine what to edit ...i just wanted to know tht after hover on div has occured once the animation should keep on playing,not only in hover state but continuously

Answer (score 0):

Maizere what you should do is add a jquery event listener for when a user hovers over the image, once that happens, change the play state rules in your .hs-wrapper img section to all say running. That is the best solution.